# ASP.Net ReportViewer - Cannot hide the document map

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I have an .aspx page that contains a `ReportViewer` control. The report displays properly, but I cannot get the document map to disappear. If you look at the two following images:

[image: Doc map expanded]
[image: Doc map collapsed]

You can see that the toggle button exists, but when I click it nothing happens. I also tried this in chrome with the developer console enabled and there were no javascript errors.

Any thoughts on what I may need to do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the `AsyncRendering` property to true and the `SizeReportToContent` property to false and the document map expand/collapse button started working properly.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/a737fdc3-6845-4304-b305-2f3c693b9599/) is a forum post that describes passing the "rc:DocMap=false" parameter to the report in order to hide the Document Map.